# I am having trouble calling upon a static recursive method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, recursion

I am trying to add up the elements in an array all while using a recursive method. However, I can't execute the method since I get an error. So, since I am using parameters in the static method, is there a way to execute it based on my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Harro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
    }

    private static void input() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Lower bound: ");
        int lower = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Upper bound: ");
        int upper = scanner.nextInt();
        arrayForm(upper, lower);
    }

    private static void arrayForm(int upper, int lower) {
        int b = 0;
        int a = Math.abs(lower) + Math.abs(upper);
        int array[] = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = lower + i;
        }
        summation(array[], b);
    }

    public static int summation(int array[], int b) {
        if (b > array.length) {
            System.out.println("Cannot continue");
            return 0;
        } else{
            int result = array[b] + summation(array, b + 1);
            System.out.println("recursion call: " + b);
            System.out.println("sum: " + result);
            System.out.println("parameter 1: " + array[b]);
            System.out.println("parameter 2: " + array[b + 1]);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please format the code a bit better?

Comment: I receive a '.class expected' where I have summation(array[], b);. am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Change this line

```
summation(array[], b);
```

to

```
summation(array, b);
```

`[]` denotes array type, you only need the identifier.

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't call array variables with []

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static void arrayForm(int upper, int lower)
  {
    int b = 0;
        int a = Math.abs(lower) + Math.abs(upper);
    int array[] = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = lower + i;
    }
    summation(array, b);
  }
```

Compile error was on that summation call. Your code now compiles but still have some runtimes errors